# imread() won't read string variable in c++

Tags: c++, file, opencv

```
char file[1024];
FILE *f;
f= popen("zenity --file-selection", "r");
std:: string result =  fgets(file,1024,f);

Mat img = imread(result, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
if(img.empty())
{
cout<<"Image is empty";
return -1;
}
resize(img,img,Size(40,56));
.........
.........
```

The output to the above code is "Image is empty"

The imread() function from opencv is not recognizing the path(string) hence unable to read the image.  How to resolve this?
Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: What's the error

Comment: the statement I have given in cout!

Comment: can you please post what the line "cout<<result" returns

Comment: Sure! Here it is.. /home/pi/kinect/gui-c++/Qt1/build-Qtwidget-Unnamed-Debug/lena.jpg

Comment: can you replace Mat img = imread(result, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); with Mat img = imread("/home/pi/kinect/gui-c++/Qt1/build-Qtwidget-Unnamed-Debug/lena.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

Comment: @janu777, I have done that and it works fine. But I don't need that. I need to choose a file from any folder. So, I couldn't stick with what you suggested.

Comment: Sure I just needed to know if the path was correct